# MetaMask ethereum.enable() not responding after logout. How to reactivate?

Tags: metamask, javascript

So I found out that after logging out of MetaMask. ethereum.enable() stop working and is not triggering the login prompt window. The only way to reactivate it, is by closing chrome, and start it once again. This is not so elegant. Is there a javascript for that?

Answer (score 1):

So apparently this was a bug in latest Metamask extension. A bug issue was opened and it should be fixed now:

https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-extension/pull/6619#issuecomment-493479084